# Quarkus Keycloak Admin settings for client id

Tags: keycloak, quarkus

I want to use Keycloak Admin with Quarkus, but I am wondering if it is possible to have an admin that can only read users from a specific realm.  I don't want to create a client-id in the admin realm.

I got always 403.

Answer (score 0):

For this purpose you must create client in a specific **Realm** with enabled **Client authentication** and **Service accounts roles**.

Then add `realm-management` client roles (select the ones you require) to Service accounts roles for created client.

After that you will be able to authenticate by *clientId* / *clientSecret*.